# Set Hyperlink Field Using SPD 2010 Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I've been doing a LOT of research to try to figure out how to do this, but nothing is working. I have a column named "Update Item" that I want to be a link to start a workflow. I have workflow setup that will populate that field. The first step sets a workflow variable to

```
 "https://www.mysite.org/site/_layouts/IniWrkflIP.aspx?List={f5c87ae4-1796-4310-aeb0-1e57edef6f87}&[%Current Item:ID%]&TemplateID={5773b102-16f1-4d45-9767-cb26db3bd72c}&Source=https://www.mysite.org/site/"
```

without the quotations. The second step updates the current item's "Update Item" field to the value of the workflow variable. When running the workflow, it errors out saying "The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more columns for the item require a different type of information." The only thing I can think is that since the variable is set as a string, the hyperlink column can't be updated to that value.

I've tried replacing

- [%Current Item:ID%] with {ItemID} per the suggestion of another site.

The workflow didn't fail, but the URL did not render correctly. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Are you purposfully omitting ID= in this section: &[%Current Item:ID%]& ? Ideally it would be &ID=[%Current Item:ID%].

Another tip would be when updating a hyperlink column, use the build a dynamic string operation and create a dynamic sting of URL, Description (comma single space is important) then use that variable in your update action to set the hyperlink field.

Comment: This is SharePoint Designer 2010, there is no Build a dynamic string operation.

Comment: Use the Set a Variable Action, then click the little ... button to open up the string builder. I keep forgetting they changed this in 2010.